# Including a file in Samrty using CSS3 Media Query

Tags: css, responsive-design, smarty

I want to include a file in smarty tpl file based on CSS3 Media query result. If screen resolution is <=640 i will use mobile header else header.tpl

One of the alternatives i came up was including both header files, and blocking/displaying one at a time. But it messes up with my page layout.

Is there a way i can set a variable or some condition to include only one header file using if statement ?

```
    <span class="display-none-mobile">
         {include file="includes/header.tpl"}
    </span>
    <span class="display-none-desktop">
         {include file="includes/header-mobile.tpl"}
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wont know the screen resolution on the server side which is where Smarty does its work, so no you cant do it with smarty. The alternative you chose would work though. That said i find it hard to believe you need two completely different sets of markup. Ideally you would apply different media based styles to a single set of markup; The same would go for the rest of the layout.

Comment: thats messing up with my layout.

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Then figure out why its messing it up and fix that. Im sure if you post a question about that the community would be happy to help :-) Also if you are actually setting one of them to `display:none;` as the class suggests im not sure how it could mees up your layout...

Comment: Thanks. So you may want to say, i must have a single header instead of two ?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: Yes, a single set of markup that is styled differently based on some media query is ideal.